# Redeploying an Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

How do you redeploy an Azure WebJob? I can see in the Azure portal how to create a WebJob and do the initial upload, but the portal does not appear to allow re-uploading changes, am I right?

I've also looked in the Kudu interface but I don't see anywhere obvious there that allows uploading updates.

So when I make an update to a job how do I release the update.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Azure portal currently doesn't support updating a WebJob but all you have to do is update the files in the correct place on your site which is: `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\{jobtype - triggered/continuous}\{jobname}'`

Read more about this here: http://www.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/

Answer (score 1):

As of Visual Studio 2013 [Update 3 and Azure SDK 2.4](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/04/announcing-release-of-visual-studio-2013-update-3-and-azure-sdk-2-4/) this is possible from within Visual Studio. Just right click and select Publish on the web job project.

Comment: There is apparently a bug however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950660/some-assemblies-not-being-included-when-deploying-azure-webjobs-from-visual-stud/25963113?iemail=1&noredirect=1#25963113

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying ? If you use then this will generate the code in your solution to deal with the deployment. I am deploying and using this plugin with VS Team Services and Azure and it is working well.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4824551-2660-4afa-aba1-1fcc1673c3d0