# Some assemblies not being included when deploying Azure webjobs from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-webjobs

I've got a Visual Studio 2013 class library project, directory structure like this:

```
\MyClassLibraryProject
    \ExternalLibraries
        3rdPartyLib.dll
    \bin
       \Debug
       \Release
    etc.
```

Inside ExternalLibraries I copied some 3rd party assemblies which I then referenced from the project (Copy local = true).  I compile the project and in my Release directory I of course see my MyClassLibraryProject.dll and the 3rd party DLLs like 3rdPartyLib.dll, etc..  Good so far.

Then I have another project (Console app - Azure webjob) from which I add a reference to the \MyClassLibraryProject\bin\Release\MyClassLibraryProject.dll (Copy local = true).  It looks like this:

```
\MyWebjob
   \bin
       \Debug
           MyWebJob.exe
           MyClassLibraryProject.dll
           3rdPartyLib.dll
```

So as you can see, when I added a reference to MyClassLibraryProject.dll (with Copy local = true), it also copied over it's dependent assembly 3rdPartyLib.dll.  Good so far.

However, when publish the webjob project to Azure (right-click Project, Publish...) 3rdPartyLib.dll is *not* deployed.  As a result, the webjobs dashboard complains it can't be found and of course the webjob doesn't execute.

Is this user error or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an issue. You need to manually deploy or add the dependencies to the webjob via nuget.

Look at this
[Relevant dependencies (DLL) not being copied when deploying using Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859089/relevant-dependencies-dll-not-being-copied-when-deploying-using-visual-studio)

Comment: << or add the dependencies to the webjob via nuget. >>  Or add them any other way, eg via direct reference and copy local, correct?  In other words, I assume nuget not specifically required for some special reason?

Comment: This issue has been fixed in our next update. It'll be out very soon.

Comment: I am not sure when the "next update" is supposed to be released, but this is still a problem. I am experiencing it now.

Comment: @Ozzy This hasn't been fixed yet. I can confirm I do have the issues still.

Comment: I have the same problem with using proto-buf.net and deploying to Azure. Azure failed to get the dll reference that was loaded with NuGet

Comment: @RickLove You can solve this by copying the files via FTP. It's not idea, but at least it will get you up and running.

Comment: @lopezbertoni I was able to solve it by putting the proto-buf dll in a dependency folder, including that dll in my git repo (for deployment), and adding a reference to that dll from the dependency folder that is included in the repo. (This way I don't have to give up the deploy from git feature, which is the main reason I use azure.)

Comment: I had the same issue when I upgraded a VS2013 web role from Azure SDK v2.5 to v2.9. Even though my local assemblies had copy to local set to true they would only do so for local testing. In the end I had to remove them, clean the project and re-add them in. The odd thing is I had a worker role in the same solution and it didn't suffer from the same issue.